# How to duplicate JavaScript unescape() Function in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, encoding, escaping, urlencode

I have a string that's encoded with `JavaScript escape()` that i need to decode in objective-c, I've searched everywhere for a solution but I can't even find what type of encoding this is.

Sample string:

```
%3Cdiv%20id%3D%27wrapper%27%3E%3Cp%3EHello%20World%21%3C/p%3E%3C/div%3E
```

Comment: what does `unescape()` do? I dont know java...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an NSString function you can use: `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a):

> Returns a new string made by replacing in the receiver all percent escapes with the matching characters as determined by a given encoding.

Typically you should  be using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` for the encoding.

Example usage:

```
NSString *escaped = @"%3Cdiv%20id%3D%27wrapper%27%3E%3Cp%3EHello%20World%21%3C/p%3E%3C/div%3E";
NSString *unescaped = [escaped stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I've found escape() works best in my situation. I just cant seem to unescape it in Objective-C.

Comment: Have you tried the function I just provided? That's exactly what it does.